# How do you select a gae entity's key_name?

Tags: python, sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to retrieve all of my Class entities key_names and not the Key.

Is there a way to do this with gae?

Here is my current code:

```
entities = db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key_name__ FROM Class").fetch(1000)
logging.info(entities)
```

which of course dosen't work because there is no property **key_name**. Does anyone know how to get the same effect?

I know how to return the Key property but what I want is the **key_name**.

Comment: you should mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key contains the key name, of course. So when you've got a list of keys, you can call `name()` on each of them to get the name component.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there might be a way to just call for all key names and save some computation but your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you.